# Why do q_nom & head_nom always give issues for models built from ThermoPower Library?

Tags: modelica, openmodelica, jmodelica

I've been working within the ThermoPower Library of OpenModelica for a while now trying to build a Combined Power Cycle by first modeling the Brayton and Rankine Power Cycles first.

Every time I attempt to use a pump, I always receive errors like:

```
[1] 10:31:00 Translation Error
[ThermoPower.Examples: 2523:70-2523:81]: Variable q_nom not found in scope ThermoPower.Examples.RankineCycle.Models.

[2] 10:31:00 Translation Error
[ThermoPower.Examples: 2531:21-2531:69]: Cyclically dependent constants or parameters found in scope : {q_nom}, {head_nom} (ignore with -d=ignoreCycles).
```

Any pump chosen, will always declare these errors for my models. I've tried many different types of solutions, all without success.

1. I've tried declaring values for the pump's component parameters using a vector format i.e. : `q_nom = {1,1,1}`. Same errors pop up when trying to simulate.
2. I've tried clicking the error directly only to be re-directed to ThermoPower.PowerPlants. Here I'm directed towards a line of code:

   function flowCharacteristic =
   ThermoPower.Functions.PumpCharacteristics.quadraticFlow (q_nom=
   q_nom, head_nom=head_nom);

Here, I've tried manually entering values for q_nom & head_nom with no success. I've also tried copying the line of code above at the top of my model trying to "redeclare" the function `flowCharacteristic`. This only results in an error about incorrectly redeclaring a class that is un-declarable.

I've tried other solutions but with no success.

If you have any advice on how to troubleshoot this issue please feel free to leave your input below!

UPDATE:

Here is the code to the model I have been working on for some time now.

model Rankine_HRSG

```
ThermoPower.PowerPlants.HRSG.Components.HE Superheater(
Cfnom_F = 0, 
Cfnom_G = 0, 
FFtype_F = ThermoPower.Choices.Flow1D.FFtypes.NoFriction, 
FFtype_G = ThermoPower.Choices.Flow1D.FFtypes.NoFriction, 
FluidPhaseStart = ThermoPower.Choices.FluidPhase.FluidPhases.Steam, 
HCtype_F = ThermoPower.Choices.Flow1D.HCtypes.Downstream, 
Kfnom_F = 0, 
Kfnom_G = 0, 
N_F = 2, 
N_G = 2, 
Nt = 1, 
Tstartbar_G = 1073.15, 
dpnom_F = 0, 
dpnom_G = 0, 
exchSurface_F = 10, 
exchSurface_G = 10, 
extSurfaceTub = 20, 
fluidNomFlowRate = 50, 
fluidNomPressure = 1e+06, 
fluidVol = 10, 
gasNomFlowRate = 102, 
gasNomPressure = 101325, 
gasQuasiStatic = false, 
gasVol = 10, 
lambda = 366, 
metalVol = 10, 
pstart_F = 5e+06, 
pstart_G = 101325, 
rhonom_F = 1000, 
rhonom_G = 0.33)
  annotation(
Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {50, 50}, extent = 
{{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 180)));

ThermoPower.PowerPlants.HRSG.Components.HE Economizer(
Cfnom_F = 0,
Cfnom_G = 0, 
FFtype_F = ThermoPower.Choices.Flow1D.FFtypes.NoFriction, 
FFtype_G = ThermoPower.Choices.Flow1D.FFtypes.NoFriction, 
FluidPhaseStart = ThermoPower.Choices.FluidPhase.FluidPhases.Liquid, 
HCtype_F = ThermoPower.Choices.Flow1D.HCtypes.Downstream, 
Kfnom_F = 0, 
Kfnom_G = 0, 
N_F = 2, 
N_G = 2, 
Nt = 1, 
Tstartbar_G = 1023.15, 
dpnom_F = 0, 
dpnom_G = 0, 
exchSurface_F = 10, 
exchSurface_G = 10, 
extSurfaceTub = 20, 
fluidNomFlowRate = 50, 
fluidNomPressure = 1e+06, 
fluidVol = 10, 
gasNomFlowRate = 102, 
gasNomPressure = 101325, 
gasVol = 10, 
lambda = 366, 
metalVol = 10, 
pstart_F = 5e+06, 
pstart_G = 101325, 
rhonom_F = 1000, 
rhonom_G = 0.33)
  annotation(
Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {50, -50}, extent = 
{{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 180)));

ThermoPower.Examples.HRB.Models.Evaporator Evaporator(
Cfnom_G = 0, 
FFtype_G = ThermoPower.Choices.Flow1D.FFtypes.NoFriction, 
Kfnom_G = 0,
N = 2, 
Tstart = 1048.15, 
cm = 376.812, 
dpnom_G = 0, 
exchSurface = 10, 
fluidNomFlowRate = 50, 
fluidNomPressure = 1e+06, 
fluidVol = 10, 
gamma = 300, 
gasNomFlowRate = 102, 
gasNomPressure = 101325, 
gasVol = 10, 
metalVol = 10, 
rhom = 8400, 
rhonom_G = 0.33)
  annotation(
Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {50, 0}, extent = {{-10, 
-10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 180)));

ThermoPower.Gas.SourcePressure FlueGasSource(
redeclare package Medium = ThermoPower.Media.FlueGas, 
R = 0, 
T = 800, 
p0 = 101325)
  annotation(
Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {94, 50}, extent = 
{{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 180)));

ThermoPower.Gas.SinkPressure FlueGasSink(
redeclare package Medium = ThermoPower.Media.FlueGas, 
R = 0, 
T = 700, 
p0 = 101325)
  annotation(
Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {10, -50}, extent = 
{{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 180)));

ThermoPower.Water.SteamTurbineStodola SteamTurbine(
PRstart = 1,
eta_iso_nom = 0.92, 
explicitIsentropicEnthalpy = true, 
partialArc_nom = 1, 
pnom = 10e5, 
wnom = 50, 
wstart = 50)
  annotation(
Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {0, 80}, extent = {{-10, 
-10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 180)));

ThermoPower.Examples.RankineCycle.Models.PrescribedPressureCondenser 
Condenser(
Vtot = 10, 
p = 1e+06)
  annotation(
Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-50, 30}, extent = 
{{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));

ThermoPower.Water.Pump Pump(
CheckValve = true,Np0 = 1, 
V = 10, 
dp0 = 0, head(start = 1), 
hstart = 1e5, 
n0 = 150, 
n_const = 150, q_single(fixed = false), rho0 = 1000, 
w0 = 50, 
w_single(fixed = false), 
wstart = 50)
  annotation(
Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-38, -12}, extent = 
{{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));

Modelica.Mechanics.Rotational.Sensors.PowerSensor PowerSensor annotation(
Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-38, 68}, extent = 
{{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 180)));

ThermoPower.Electrical.Generator Generator annotation(
Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-68, 68}, extent = 
{{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 180)));

Modelica.Blocks.Continuous.FirstOrder firstOrder1 annotation(
Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-50, 92}, extent = 
{{-8, -8}, {8, 8}}, rotation = 180)));

Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealOutput Power annotation(
Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-110, 0}, extent = 
{{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 180), iconTransformation(origin = 
{-110, 0}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 180)));
inner ThermoPower.System system annotation(
Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {90, 90}, extent = 
{{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
equation
connect(PowerSensor.flange_b, Generator.shaft) annotation(
Line(points = {{-48, 68}, {-59, 68}}));
connect(SteamTurbine.shaft_b, PowerSensor.flange_a) annotation(
Line(points = {{-6, 80}, {-14, 80}, {-14, 68}, {-28, 68}}));
connect(SteamTurbine.outlet, Condenser.steamIn) annotation(
Line(points = {{-8, 72}, {-8, 52}, {-50, 52}, {-50, 40}}, color = {0, 0, 
255}));
connect(Superheater.waterOut, SteamTurbine.inlet) annotation(
Line(points = {{50, 60}, {50, 64}, {8, 64}, {8, 72}}, color = {0, 0, 
255}));
connect(Evaporator.waterOut, Superheater.waterIn) annotation(
Line(points = {{50, 10}, {50, 10}, {50, 40}, {50, 40}}, color = {0, 0, 
255}));
connect(Economizer.waterOut, Evaporator.waterIn) annotation(
Line(points = {{50, -40}, {50, -40}, {50, -10}, {50, -10}}, color = {0, 0, 
255}));
connect(firstOrder1.y, Power) annotation(
Line(points = {{-58, 92}, {-90, 92}, {-90, 0}, {-102, 0}, {-102, 0}, 
{-110, 0}}, color = {0, 0, 127}));
connect(PowerSensor.power, firstOrder1.u) annotation(
Line(points = {{-30, 80}, {-30, 80}, {-30, 92}, {-40, 92}, {-40, 92}, 
{-40, 92}}, color = {0, 0, 127}));
connect(Condenser.waterOut, Pump.infl) annotation(
Line(points = {{-50, 20}, {-50, -10}, {-46, -10}}, color = {0, 0, 255}));
connect(Pump.outfl, Economizer.waterIn) annotation(
Line(points = {{-32, -4}, {-26, -4}, {-26, -80}, {50, -80}, {50, -60}, 
{50, -60}}, color = {0, 0, 255}));
connect(Economizer.gasOut, FlueGasSink.flange) annotation(
Line(points = {{40, -50}, {20, -50}, {20, -50}, {20, -50}}, color = {159, 
159, 223}));
connect(Superheater.gasOut, Evaporator.gasIn) annotation(
Line(points = {{40, 50}, {20, 50}, {20, 30}, {80, 30}, {80, 0}, {60, 0}}, 
color = {159, 159, 223}));
connect(Evaporator.gasOut, Economizer.gasIn) annotation(
Line(points = {{40, 0}, {20, 0}, {20, -26}, {20, -26}, {20, -30}, {80, 
-30}, {80, -50}, {60, -50}, {60, -50}}, color = {159, 159, 223}));
connect(FlueGasSource.flange, Superheater.gasIn) annotation(
Line(points = {{84, 50}, {60, 50}, {60, 50}, {60, 50}}, color = {159, 159, 
223}));

annotation(
uses(ThermoPower(version = "3.1"), Modelica(version = "3.2.2")));end 
Rankine_HRSG;
```

Comment: Are you using the current master of https://github.com/casella/ThermoPower ?
And have you checked, if there is a declaration of q_nom inside the model ThermoPower.Examples.RankineCycle.Models.PrescribedSpeedPump?

Comment: @f.wue I have checked out the current master that Casella provided the community. I believe but am not completely certain I opened all of the respected ThermoPower Library components correctly that were provided on that master file. There were issues opening the packag.mo file ... see ticket #5348 ( https://trac.openmodelica.org/OpenModelica/ticket/5348#comment:4 ) to understand the difficulties I had with opening that file.

The reason I'm uncertain about if I opened that correctly is because with those new files, I still cannot simulate the Rankine Cycle.

Comment: Also, there is a declaration of q_nom within ThermoPower.Examples.RankineCycle.Models.PrescribedSpeedPump ... It occurs in two lines :

parameter Modelica.SIunits.VolumeFlowRate q_nom[3]  &  function flowCharacteristic =
      ThermoPower.Functions.PumpCharacteristics.quadraticFlow (q_nom=q_nom,
        head_nom=head_nom); 

Where changing these values do not effect the errors produced from q_nom. 

I must be missing some sort of details on how to exactly move forward with (1) the master files and (2) declaring q_nom correctly in either the model or inside the baseclass.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to reproduce the error using OMEdit v1.12.0 (64-bit). However, it seems that it is a bug with the OpenModelica-Version we are using. Same model in Dymola and no Errors/Warnings.
Furthermore, simulating the example works for me in OpenModelica.
Also, using this line:

```
  function flowCharacteristic =
      ThermoPower.Functions.PumpCharacteristics.quadraticFlow (q_nom={1,2,3},
        head_nom={1,2,3});
```

Fixes this translation error. Maybe try to download an other build of OM. If you use the latest release, downgrade, if you use an old release, upgrade. If you can not fix this error using the line i presented, please provide the version of the ThermoLib and OM you are using.

**EDIT:** Looking at your model, there are some issues:

1. When using a pump for your rankine cycle, you have to select a function for the flow characteristic and give values for `q_nom` and `head_nom`.
2. The cycle you provided lacks a mover. The gas has to be moved through your cycle either by a pump or a `massFlowSource`.
3. You declared a parameter `partialArc_nom = 1` which is not used in the model SteamTurbine of ThermoPower.

Fixing all these errors results in a model which translates both in OM and Dymola without errors. The simulation does not work because some inital values and equations cause trouble. Changing the gas-medium or setting consitent initialValues by propagating the inital values of each submodel to the top-level may solve this problem. This could also be caused by the dummy-values i've set for the paramteres `q_nom` and `head_nom`. Choosing physical values for these parameters is up to you.
Find below the fixed code which worked for me.

```
model Rankine_HRSG

ThermoPower.PowerPlants.HRSG.Components.HE Superheater(
Cfnom_F = 0,
Cfnom_G = 0,
FFtype_F = ThermoPower.Choices.Flow1D.FFtypes.NoFriction,
FFtype_G = ThermoPower.Choices.Flow1D.FFtypes.NoFriction,
FluidPhaseStart = ThermoPower.Choices.FluidPhase.FluidPhases.Steam,
HCtype_F = ThermoPower.Choices.Flow1D.HCtypes.Downstream,
Kfnom_F = 0,
Kfnom_G = 0,
N_F = 2,
N_G = 2,
Nt = 1,
dpnom_F = 0,
dpnom_G = 0,
exchSurface_F = 10,
exchSurface_G = 10,
extSurfaceTub = 20,
fluidNomFlowRate = 50,
fluidVol = 10,
gasNomFlowRate = 102,
gasQuasiStatic = false,
gasVol = 10,
lambda = 366,
metalVol = 10,
rhonom_F = 1000,
rhonom_G = 0.33,
    gasNomPressure=101325,
    fluidNomPressure=1000000,
    rhomcm=1000,
    Tstartbar_G=1073.15,
    pstart_G=101325,
    pstart_F=5000000)
  annotation (
Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {50, 50}, extent=
{{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 180)));

ThermoPower.PowerPlants.HRSG.Components.HE Economizer(
Cfnom_F = 0,
Cfnom_G = 0,
FFtype_F = ThermoPower.Choices.Flow1D.FFtypes.NoFriction,
FFtype_G = ThermoPower.Choices.Flow1D.FFtypes.NoFriction,
FluidPhaseStart = ThermoPower.Choices.FluidPhase.FluidPhases.Liquid,
HCtype_F = ThermoPower.Choices.Flow1D.HCtypes.Downstream,
Kfnom_F = 0,
Kfnom_G = 0,
N_F = 2,
N_G = 2,
Nt = 1,
dpnom_F = 0,
dpnom_G = 0,
exchSurface_F = 10,
exchSurface_G = 10,
extSurfaceTub = 20,
fluidNomFlowRate = 50,
fluidVol = 10,
gasNomFlowRate = 102,
gasVol = 10,
lambda = 366,
metalVol = 10,
rhonom_F = 1000,
rhonom_G = 0.33,
    gasNomPressure=101325,
    fluidNomPressure=1000000,
    rhomcm=1000,
    Tstartbar_G=1023.15,
    pstart_G=101325,
    pstart_F=5000000)
  annotation (
Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {50, -50}, extent=
{{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 180)));

ThermoPower.Examples.HRB.Models.Evaporator Evaporator(
Cfnom_G = 0,
FFtype_G = ThermoPower.Choices.Flow1D.FFtypes.NoFriction,
Kfnom_G = 0,
N = 2,
cm = 376.812,
dpnom_G = 0,
exchSurface = 10,
fluidNomFlowRate = 50,
fluidVol = 10,
gamma = 300,
gasNomFlowRate = 102,
gasVol = 10,
metalVol = 10,
rhom = 8400,
rhonom_G = 0.33,
    gasNomPressure=101325,
    fluidNomPressure=1000000,
    Tstart=1048.15)
  annotation (
Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {50, 0}, extent = {{-10,
-10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 180)));

ThermoPower.Gas.SourceMassFlow FlueGasSource(
redeclare package Medium = ThermoPower.Media.FlueGas,
    p0=101325,
    T=800,
    w0=1)
  annotation (
Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {94, 50}, extent=
{{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 180)));

ThermoPower.Gas.SinkPressure FlueGasSink(
redeclare package Medium = ThermoPower.Media.FlueGas,
R = 0,
T = 700,
p0 = 101325)
  annotation (
Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {10, -50}, extent=
{{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 180)));

ThermoPower.Water.SteamTurbineStodola SteamTurbine(
PRstart = 1,
eta_iso_nom = 0.92,
explicitIsentropicEnthalpy = true,
wnom = 50,
wstart = 50,
    pnom=1000000,
    Kt=1)
  annotation (
Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {0, 80}, extent = {{-10,
-10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 180)));
//partialArc_nom = 1,

ThermoPower.Examples.RankineCycle.Models.PrescribedPressureCondenser
Condenser(
Vtot = 10, p=1000000)
  annotation (
Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-50, 30}, extent=
{{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));

ThermoPower.Water.Pump Pump(
CheckValve = true,Np0 = 1,
V = 10,
dp0 = 0, head(start = 1),
hstart = 1e5,
n0 = 150,
n_const = 150, q_single(fixed = false), rho0 = 1000,
w0 = 50,
w_single(fixed = false),
wstart = 50,
    redeclare function efficiencyCharacteristic =
        ThermoPower.Functions.PumpCharacteristics.constantEfficiency (eta_nom=0.8),
    redeclare function flowCharacteristic =
        ThermoPower.Functions.PumpCharacteristics.linearFlow (q_nom={0.5,1},
          head_nom={10,15}))
  annotation (
Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-38, -12}, extent=
{{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));

Modelica.Mechanics.Rotational.Sensors.PowerSensor PowerSensor annotation (
Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-38, 68}, extent=
{{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 180)));

ThermoPower.Electrical.Generator Generator annotation (
Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-68, 68}, extent=
{{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 180)));

Modelica.Blocks.Continuous.FirstOrder firstOrder1 annotation (
Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-50, 92}, extent=
{{-8, -8}, {8, 8}}, rotation = 180)));

Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealOutput Power annotation (
Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-110, 0}, extent=
{{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 180), iconTransformation(origin=
{-110, 0}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 180)));
inner ThermoPower.System system annotation (
Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {90, 90}, extent=
{{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
equation
connect(PowerSensor.flange_b, Generator.shaft) annotation (
Line(points={{-48,68},{-59.4,68}}));
connect(SteamTurbine.shaft_b, PowerSensor.flange_a) annotation (
Line(points={{-6.4,80},{-14,80},{-14,68},{-28,68}}));
connect(SteamTurbine.outlet, Condenser.steamIn) annotation (
Line(points = {{-8, 72}, {-8, 52}, {-50, 52}, {-50, 40}}, color = {0, 0,
255}));
connect(Superheater.waterOut, SteamTurbine.inlet) annotation (
Line(points = {{50, 60}, {50, 64}, {8, 64}, {8, 72}}, color = {0, 0,
255}));
connect(Evaporator.waterOut, Superheater.waterIn) annotation (
Line(points = {{50, 10}, {50, 10}, {50, 40}, {50, 40}}, color = {0, 0,
255}));
connect(Economizer.waterOut, Evaporator.waterIn) annotation (
Line(points = {{50, -40}, {50, -40}, {50, -10}, {50, -10}}, color = {0, 0,
255}));
connect(firstOrder1.y, Power) annotation (
Line(points={{-58.8,92},{-90,92},{-90,0},{-102,0},{-102,0},{-110,0}},
            color = {0, 0, 127}));
connect(PowerSensor.power, firstOrder1.u) annotation (
Line(points={{-30,79},{-30,79},{-30,92},{-40,92},{-40,92},{-40.4,92}},
            color = {0, 0, 127}));
connect(Condenser.waterOut, Pump.infl) annotation (
Line(points = {{-50, 20}, {-50, -10}, {-46, -10}}, color = {0, 0, 255}));
connect(Pump.outfl, Economizer.waterIn) annotation (
Line(points={{-32,-5},{-26,-5},{-26,-80},{50,-80},{50,-60},{50,-60}},
            color = {0, 0, 255}));
connect(Economizer.gasOut, FlueGasSink.flange) annotation (
Line(points = {{40, -50}, {20, -50}, {20, -50}, {20, -50}}, color = {159,
159, 223}));
connect(Superheater.gasOut, Evaporator.gasIn) annotation (
Line(points = {{40, 50}, {20, 50}, {20, 30}, {80, 30}, {80, 0}, {60, 0}},
color = {159, 159, 223}));
connect(Evaporator.gasOut, Economizer.gasIn) annotation (
Line(points = {{40, 0}, {20, 0}, {20, -26}, {20, -26}, {20, -30}, {80,
-30}, {80, -50}, {60, -50}, {60, -50}}, color = {159, 159, 223}));
connect(FlueGasSource.flange, Superheater.gasIn) annotation (
Line(points = {{84, 50}, {60, 50}, {60, 50}, {60, 50}}, color = {159, 159,
223}));

annotation (
uses(ThermoPower(version = "3.1"), Modelica(version = "3.2.2")));
end Rankine_HRSG;
```

Comment: Hey @f.wue 

So I am currently using the OMEdit v 1.13.1 (64-bit). I tried copying that line of code into the top of my model however I still receive the error messages `[1] 11:38:16 Translation Error
[ThermoPower.Examples: 2509:70-2509:81]: Variable q_nom not found in scope ThermoPower.Examples.RankineCycle.Models.

[2] 11:38:17 Translation Error
[ThermoPower.Examples: 2517:21-2517:69]: Cyclically dependent constants or parameters found in scope : {q_nom}, {head_nom} (ignore with -d=ignoreCycles).` and so on. This model instantiation was attempted using the Master Branch ThermoPower.

Comment: I can still try and downgrade the OMEdit package. I'm just very frustrated as to why the flowrate and head variables continue to give me model errors on every iteration of the Rankine cycle I have done. Over ~15 iterations of this model, simplifying the component builds each time has yet to yield a successful simulation of the model. 

I would also be happy to share the code to my model with you. 

Let me know what you think! Thank you for you time and effort into the matter, I really appreciate it.

Comment: If you use the current master you could indeed update your question providing the model code of the model you want to simulate. If this code works for me in OM and/or Dymola, we can make sure this is a problem with your OM installation.

Comment: Hey thanks for taking the time to look at my script and assess it on your OM/Dymola setting. I inserted the code I have been working on above in the question that has been updated. The error has changed and is not the same as the ones I have mentioned above. OMEdit gives me very **inconsistent** results sometimes. I'll instantiate/check it one day and it will give me different results the next. However, the majority of errors I have come across while trying to build and simulate a Rankine cycle pertain towards variables from whatever pump model I use.

Comment: I am also wondering if you are able to run the Rankine Cycle Example off of the ThermoPower Library. Since I started using OpenModelica since January, I have only been able to run and simulate the example once, and that was this past Monday. All other attempts to simulate after that successful run have failed as normal. I am curious to see if it is the OM installation that is breaking the library example model, or if it is the outdated/bugged ThermoPower library as a whole that is causing me these failed simulations. Let me know when you get a chance, once again, I am very thankful for thehelp