# How do I fix "Variable Not Found in Scope" within Modelica

Tags: modelica, openmodelica, jmodelica

I recently tried to instantiate the WindFarm.mo located within PowerSystems.Examples.Wind.WindFarm and I received an error message reading:

```
[1] 08:40:50 Translation Error
[PowerSystems.AC3ph.Machines: 667:58-667:76]: Variable system.f_nom not found in scope PowerSystems.AC3ph.Machines.Partials.AsynchronBase.
```

I've had this problem before, where the error message always redirects the user to a different class or partial class.

This error was just really confusing to me because **no where** within the WindFarm.mo was there a use of any model from PowerSystems.AC3ph.Machines library.

All the components used within the WindFarm.mo does indeed have components used within PowerSystems.AC3ph however, that is where it ends. The variable `n_r`, I believe the rotor speed, is not even used within my model.

If you have any knowledge in this subject, advice or suggestions please feel free to leave a comment! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As i've answered in [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54792756/why-do-q-nom-head-nom-always-give-issues-for-models-built-from-thermopower-lib?noredirect=1#comment96402429_54792756) question of yours, it is likely a bug in OM. It only occurs when opening the model (at least for me) and checking/Simulation works fine.
The example `WindFarm.mo` uses `PowerSystems.AC3ph.Machines.Partials.AsynchronBase` as the generators of the wind-turbines extend from the partial model.